# Будет ли AsyncTask ждать выполнение другого потока внутри doInBackground?

Tags: java, android

Общая картина такая запускается `AsyncTask` в методе `onPreExecute` выполняется подготовка. Потом в `doInBackground`, внутри которого последовательно выполняется поток за потоком в `newSingleThreadExecutor()` и когда в `newSingleThreadExecutor()` заканчивается выполнение всех потоков то `doInBackground` заканчивает свое выполнение, запускается последний метод `onPostExecute` в котором я пишу юзеру, что все прошло успешно.

Вопрос в том, действительно ли `doInBackground` будет ждать пока `newSingleThreadExecutor()` внутри него выполнит все свои потоки?

Вот код как это работает у меня

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            MyDialog dialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                dialog = MyDialog.newInstance(R.layout.activity_good_job_dialog);
                dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                pool.submit(new ZipUtil());
                pool.submit(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sentPhoto();
                    }
                });
                pool.submit(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        closeCamera();
                        stopBackgroundThread();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                pool.shutdown();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SuccessActivity.class)
                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));

            }
        }.execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doInBackground не будет ждать выполнение других потоков, запущенных внутри него. Он их запустит и сразу последует вызов onPostExecute, но потоки запущенные в doInBackground все еще будут выполнять свою работу. Зачем вам запускать в doInBackground отдельный поток, если это уже является отдельным потоком, тем более если потоки выполняются в newSingleThreadExecutor, т.е. созданные вами потоки будут выполнятся по очереди в одном. На вашем месте я бы просто последовательно вызвал методы в doInBackground, не создавая для их выполнения еще отдельные потоки в doInBackground.

Comment: Но в моем примере визуально для юзера код работает намного быстрее так как юзер не ждет выполнения в `doInBackground`. И в целом сохраняется порядок... Но у меня вопрос согласно вашего ответа, почему не умирает `newSingleThreadExecutor` , если как вы говорите `doInBackground ` который его вызвал уже закончил выполнение и умер?

Comment: правильно, что быстрее, но в onPostExecute вы говорите юзеру, что все прошло успешно, но на самом деле это не так. А на вопрос почему не умирает newSingleThreadExecutor, приведите его код пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавил,.......

Comment: Вычитал что даже если метод уже завершился, но еще выполняются порожденные им потоки, то система будет ждать их завершения.